# Installing Node from NodeSource on Docker image vs using Node official Docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I'm building a Docker image with Node.js to use it in my CICD workflow to build the Node application code. During my research, I got this information (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) where we can install the Node.js from Nodesource with Ubuntu/Debian as base image. So, I followed this and created a Docker image with Node.js and some other packages in it. And when I run this Docker image, I'm able to run linux commands as required.

I found there are official Node images in Docker Hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/node). I tried to build another image with base as Node image from Docker Hub and installed some additional packages that are required for me. When I run the Docker image that I built with official Node image as base, I see below when the image is started. But I'm not able to run any linux commands here.

```
Welcome to Node.js v16.20.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

What is the purpose of Node images in Docker Hub? When these are used and when Node from Nodesource is used in Docker images? And is there any way to run the linux commands in the image that is built based on Node image from Docker Hub?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` instructions. The official images have pre-defined `CMD [ "node" ]` instruction, which gets executed when you run the container based on those images. That's what you see there. You can override this (and this is exactly what's done in most of the cases) by defining your own `CMD` instruction. For example:

```
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

To answer your 2nd question: yes, it's possible to run Unix commands inside the official Node.js images (provided that it's been built from a Linux distro and `bash` is installed). You can even extend these images by installing any extra libraries and packages you need for your application. Like so:

```
FROM node
RUN apt install chromium
# ...
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Hope that clears out your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That helps. But in which scenario, NodeSource is used and when the node docker image is used?

Comment: [Node.js binaries](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) are solely used for native installations. If you have Ubuntu or Fedora installed on your computer, you use that for installing Node.js on your system. Moreover, if you rent a VPS somewhere in the cloud, you can also install Node.js there using the binary distributions. *continued*

Comment: On the other hand, [official Node.js Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) are used for running Node.js in a container. These images are very lightweight and self-contained, hence lightning fast to load. And, Docker is supported cross-platform, so you don't run into compatibility issues.